# How to track user's credit card transactions in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Any recommendations for good APIs/services that let an app track a user's credit card/debit card purchases?

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, could you mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'tracking user's credit card transactions'. I assume you mean in the app and not in the real world? Otherwise this would be a major breach in a bank's security. If you mean you wish to see what a user has purchased in your app; Stripe's API can be used to create a customer_id where all purchases made in your app can be tied back to that specific customer;

https://stripe.com/gb?utm_campaign=paid_brand-UK_en_Search_Brand_Stripe-2032860449&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&ad_content=355351450265&utm_term=kwd-94834400&utm_matchtype=e&utm_adposition=&utm_device=c